# How to use unordered_map in cython?

Tags: python, c++, cython, missing-data, ordered-map

I want a step by step guide, how to use unordered_map in cython.

I've included file unordered_map.pxd into Cython/Includes/libcpp from https://gist.github.com/ikuyamada/3265267 and use 3 other files:

main.py:

```
import pyximport;
pyximport.install()
from foo import F

F()
```

foo.pyx:

```
from libcpp.unordered_map cimport unordered_map


def F():
    cdef unordered_map[int, int] my_map
    my_map[1]=11
    my_map[2]=12
    print my_map[1],my_map[2]
```

foo.pyxbld: (to compile foo.pyx into C++)

```
def make_ext(modname, pyxfilename):
    from distutils.extension import Extension
    return Extension(name=modname,
                     sources=[pyxfilename],
                     language='C++')
```

When I run test.py, I get error:

```
foo.cpp
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\xlocale(342) : warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
C:\Users\kitov\.pyxbld\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\pyrex\foo.cpp(316) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'tr1/unordered_map': No such file or directory
```

I use Win7, Python 2.7 64bit, VS2008 Professional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem:

1) I needed to install Visual C++ 2008 Feature Pack from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6922

2) I needed to use the following unordered_map.pxd:

```
from libcpp.utility cimport pair

cdef extern from "<unordered_map>" namespace "std::tr1":
    cdef cppclass unordered_map[T, U]:
        cppclass iterator:
            pair[T, U]& operator*() nogil
            iterator operator++() nogil
            iterator operator--() nogil
            bint operator==(iterator) nogil
            bint operator!=(iterator) nogil
        unordered_map()
        unordered_map(unordered_map&)
        U& operator[](T&) nogil
        # unordered_map& operator=(unordered_map&)
        U& at(T&) nogil
        iterator begin() nogil
        void clear() nogil
        size_t count(T&) nogil
        bint empty() nogil
        iterator end() nogil
        pair[iterator, iterator] equal_range(T&) nogil
        void erase(iterator) nogil
        void erase(iterator, iterator) nogil
        size_t erase(T&) nogil
        iterator find(T&) nogil
        pair[iterator, bint] insert(pair[T, U]) nogil
        iterator insert(iterator, pair[T, U]) nogil
        void insert(input_iterator, input_iterator)
        size_t max_size() nogil
        void rehash(size_t)
        size_t size() nogil
        void swap(unordered_map&) nogil
```

One line was changed, compared to https://gist.github.com/ikuyamada/3265267:

```
cdef extern from "<tr1/unordered_map>" namespace "std::tr1":
```

->

```
cdef extern from "<unordered_map>" namespace "std::tr1":
```

Answer (score 2):

if you've already compiled `foo`, I don't think you'll need to run `pyximport.install()`. That might have messed it up since `pyximport` re-compiles the source code, but you didn't provide any compiler-args to `pyximport`, so it compiled with default settings (i.e. not knowing `foo` is a cpp source file).

main.py:

```
from foo import F
F()
```

foo.py**x**: <-- don't forget the x

```
#distutils: language = c++
from libcpp.unordered_map cimport unordered_map

def F():
    cdef unordered_map[int, int] my_map
    my_map[1]=11
    my_map[2]=12
    print my_map[1],my_map[2]
```

Comment: Of course, I meant foo.pyx. I corrected the question.

Comment: In fact, pyximport receives compilation arguments when file foo.pyxbld is created in the same directory. In my case foo.cpp is compiled.